# Why does the Rails asset pipeline not work surprise-free with subdirectories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.2, and am somewhat confused about the handling of subdirectories and relative paths of the asset pipeline.

### My situation

I'm trying to include four code files in (`javascripts/edit`), one of them being in the subdirectory `javascripts/edit/ckeditor`, in a manifest file, (`javascripts/edit/all.js`). I'm not including these in the application.js because I want to include these scripts *only* on certain pages.

Doing `//= require ckeditor/ckeditor` doesn't work. Doing `//= require mycode` (to require `javascripts/edit/mycode.js`), too, doesn't work, apparently because mycode.js is in the "edit" subdirectory of the javascripts "root" folder. To make it work, I had to put this:

```
//= require ./ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require ./json2
//= require ./cssjson
//= require ./mycode
```

inside of my manifest `all.js`. Note that this:

```
//= require edit/ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require edit/json2
//= require edit/cssjson
//= require edit/mycode
```

works exactly the same, even though `all.js` itself is already in the `edit` subdirectory.

So my question is, why does this work this way? I would expect to be able to put manifest files in subdirectories and just include files that are in that same subdirectory (e.g. `//= require json2`), but apparently, all `//= require` directives in any file below `app/assets/javascripts` always are relative to that "root" folder, not the subdirectory that the manifest files are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, why does this work this way?

Because when [Rails compiles the assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), it's compiling from a central point, not your subdirectory. The manifest system works based on the assets' root path (the documentation says `The first feature of the pipeline is to concatenate assets`), consequently your assets will be compiled from the `application.js` file

You have to remember when Rails runs, it's not loading the assets dynamically. It's designed to load `application.css` / `application.js` all the time, and it's then up to the developer to delegate assets which they wish to load on specific pages

The way we do this is to include all the "constant" files in our `application.js` file, and then load controller-specific assets in the layout. This allows us to only call things like JQuery all the time, whilst we may call specific JQuery plugins for certain controllers:

---

**Including The Right Assets In The Right Places**

This is what we do:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller_name, media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag controller_name, "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>


#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.draggable
//= require_tree ./jquery
//= require_tree ./extra
//= require turbolinks

#app/assets/javascripts/users.js.erb
//= require ** anything you want **
```

This allows you to have a lot more control over which assets you're loading

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I feel it only halfways answers the question- but now I see that my actual question, which is, why this behaviour was chosen to be the behaviour of Rails, might be better a question at the Rails community itself.

Your suggestion is interesting, but not exactly what I want: It requires that I have **controller-wide** stylesheets and scripts, while I only want to include certain scripts and stylesheets in the **edit action** of the controller. I will keep this in mind, though.

Comment: No problem - glad it helped! Have you thought about putting some logic into your layout? Something like this: `<% if params[:action] == "edit" %><%= javascript_include_tag etc etc etc %><% end %>`